# Issue with ionic 3 movefile function

Tags: typescript, file, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

[image]I'm trying to use moveFile function which is provided from file native plugin, i cannot upload screenshots since it's a private project belongs to my company but i will try to explain as much as i can
I use camera native plugin to take photos, camera is working very well and the photos are showing, but when i try to use file native plugin (moveFile) method just to move taken photos to files directory rather than cache, nothing happens!
file and fileError are imported in the page TS, file is provided in App Module as well

Here is my TS (Updated):

```
getImageFromCamera() {
const options: CameraOptions = {
  quality: 20,
  saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
  sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
  encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  allowEdit: true
};
this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
  this.imageUrl = imageData;
  let imageName = imageData.substr(imageData.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
  this.file.checkDir(this.file.externalRootDirectory, 'DEMO')
    .then(() => {
      this.fileCreated = true;
    }, (err) => {
    });
  if (this.fileCreated) {
  }
  else {
    this.file.createDir(this.file.externalRootDirectory, "DEMO", true)
      .then((res) => {
      }, (err) => {
      });
  }
  let tempPath = this.imageUrl.substr(0, this.imageUrl.lastIndexOf('/') +1);
  let androidPath = this.file.externalRootDirectory + '/DEMO/';
  this.file.moveFile(tempPath, imageName, androidPath, imageName)
    .then((res) => {
      this.file.readAsDataURL(androidPath, imageName)
        .then((res) => {
          this.images.push(res);
        }, (err) => {
          console.log("Error in Image Get Path---");
          console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
        });
    }, (err) => {
    });
  // this.toDataURL(this.imageUrl, function (dataUrl) {
  //  console.log('RESULT:' + dataUrl);
  //  this.images.push(this.imageUrl);
  // });
 }, (err) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
 });
}
toDataURL(url, callback) {
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function () {
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = function () {
    callback(reader.result);
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
 };
xhr.open('GET', url);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.send();
}
```

My HTML

```
<ion-item>
  <h5>Choose files to upload</h5>
  <button (tap)="getImageFromCamera()" item-end ion-button round outline 
   color="sideBar">Upload</button>
</ion-item>
<ion-slides *ngIf="images.length >= 1">
  <ion-slide style="float: left;" *ngFor="let image of images; let i = 
   index;" class="image-container">
    <ion-icon (tap)="onDeletePhoto(i)" class="icon-container" name="close- 
     circle"></ion-icon>
    <img [src]="image" width="100">
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
<ion-item>
```

As you can see i tried to view the 4 parameters on the screen with the photoError string, and everything is looking very good, the old path is right, the name, the new path and new name is right, but the image is not moved from the pictures folder, i find the file folder on my phone is empty, and the image still in pictures folder, the imageUrl string is also showing the correct path of the image (the new one), when i try to set the imageUrl to the old path, also image is not showing, i tried the app on another Android device, also same issue so it's not from my phone.

Anyone has any idea? if you have any questions that i didn't provide an answer for, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here i've created Demo for you, this code takes photo from camera and save into folder ,then reads that image from local path and displays on screen, i have tested also, works fine for me, this should work well now.

**Home.ts**

Make sure you have imported all packages

**import { Component } from '@angular/core'; 

import { NavController, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';

import {Camera, CameraOptions} from "@ionic-native/camera";

import {File} from '@ionic-native/file';**

```
export class HomePage {

public imageURI: any;
public imageName: any;
public fileCreated: boolean = false;
public imageString: any;
resultImageArray: any;
```

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              private file: File,
              private camera: Camera,
              private toastCtrl: ToastController,) {

}

```
getImageFromCamera() {


    const options: CameraOptions = {
        quality: 20,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
        destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
        encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        allowEdit: true
    };

    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
        this.imageURI = imageData;
        this.imageName = imageData.substr(imageData.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

        // Create a folder in memory location
        this.file.checkDir(this.file.externalRootDirectory, 'ImagesDemo')
            .then(() => {
                this.fileCreated = true;
            }, (err) => {
                console.log("checkDir: Error");
                console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
                this.presentToast("checkDir Failed");
            });
        if (this.fileCreated) {
            this.presentToast("Directory Already exist");
        }
        else {
            this.file.createDir(this.file.externalRootDirectory, "ImagesDemo", true)
                .then((res) => {
                    this.presentToast("Directory Created");
                }, (err) => {
                    console.log("Directory Creation Error:");
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
                });
        }

        //FILE MOVE CODE
        let tempPath = this.imageURI.substr(0, this.imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        let androidPath = this.file.externalRootDirectory + '/ImagesDemo/';
        this.imageString = androidPath + this.imageName;

        this.file.moveFile(tempPath, this.imageName, androidPath, this.imageName)
            .then((res) => {
                this.presentToast("Image Saved Successfully");
                this.readImage(this.imageString);

            }, (err) => {
                console.log("Image Copy Failed");
                console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
                this.presentToast("Image Copy Failed");
            });
        //Complete File Move Code

        this.toDataURL(this.imageURI, function (dataUrl) {
            console.log('RESULT:' + dataUrl);
        });
    }, (err) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
        this.presentToast(JSON.stringify(err));
    });
}


presentToast(msg) {
    let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
        message: msg,
        duration: 2000
    });
    toast.present();
}

toDataURL(url, callback) {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function () {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function () {
            callback(reader.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
    };
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.send();
}



readImage(filePath) {
    let tempPath = filePath.substr(0, filePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    let imageName = filePath.substr(filePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

    this.file.readAsDataURL(tempPath, imageName)
        .then((res) => {
            this.presentToast("Image Get Done");
            this.resultImageArray = res;
        }, (err) => {
            this.presentToast("Image Get Error");
        });
}
```

}

**Home.html**

```
 <button ion-button   item-end icon-start block  (click)="getImageFromCamera()">Click Here</button>


  <ion-card *ngIf=resultImageArray>
<img src="{{resultImageArray}}"/></ion-card>
```

And now we are ready to go, just run into device, you'll have output as you want.

hare i have also attached output of my code.

[image]

Comment: Yes it's showing a data url now but with no image, showing only broken image small icon

Comment: and it takes very long time to show this icon till it generates base64 data url

Comment: can you share your code? so i can figure out whats wrong..!

Comment: i commented the previous function this.toDataUrl because i'm now using the last one you provided

Comment: i have edited my response, please go through updated response.. :)

Comment: I copied your code and made it the same to my TS and HTML, still does not show the image, look on the question desc. i updated with an image of what is showing to me after i added your code.

Comment: are you doing this using android or iphone? i'm using android

Comment: i'm also using android phone..code should work , don't know why it is not working... do one effort, create new project and copy paste my code in home.ts & home.html, you also need to install packages: camera, file, file-transfer, then run. and let me know if that works or not. this  will take max 15-20 min, but we will have idea about what is going wrong..either code or something else.

Comment: you can download my demo from this link:  [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PSX0lz3EE9-VfG_q9f2EchlcsNbX38wU)

Comment: i already tried that, and it's working in a new project, i think it's a problem with plugins version, however i will figure it out, thank you very much for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Refer this code, i have done moving image to specified folder, with this code. hop this will help you..
**here is my code:**

```
  getImageFromCamera() {

    const options: CameraOptions = {
        quality: 20,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
        destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
        encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        allowEdit: true
    };

    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {

        this.imageURI = imageData;
        this.imageName = imageData.substr(imageData.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

        // Create a folder 'DEMO' in memory location of device to store image

        this.file.checkDir(this.file.externalRootDirectory, 'DEMO')
            .then(() => {
                this.fileCreated = true;
            }, (err) => {
                console.log("checkDir: Error");
            });
        if (this.fileCreated) {
            this.presentToast("Directory Already exist");
        }
        else {
            this.file.createDir(this.file.externalRootDirectory, "DEMO", true)
                .then((res) => {
                    this.presentToast("Directory Created");
                }, (err) => {
                    console.log("Directory Creation Error:");
                });
        }

        //FILE MOVE CODE

        let tempPath = this.imageURI.substr(0, this.imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        let androidPath = this.file.externalRootDirectory + '/DEMO/';

        this.file.moveFile(tempPath, this.imageName, androidPath, this.imageName)
            .then((res) => {
                this.presentToast("Image Moved Successfully");

            }, (err) => {
                this.presentToast("Image Moved Failed");
            });
        //Complete File Move Code

        this.toDataURL(this.imageURI, function (dataUrl) {
            console.log('RESULT:' + dataUrl);
        });
    }, (err) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
    });

}
 toDataURL(url, callback) {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function () {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function () {
            callback(reader.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
    };
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i will try it and update you.

Comment: Thank you, it's better than my code, it's creating the dir and moving photo to it, but issue is when i try to show the photo on the html, i dont get to see anything, i tried to see the path in the img tag, it was correct, and if i tried to show an image from the project assets folder, it's shown but from the taken image it's not working, do you have any idea why this is happening? my HTML still the same as the one mentioned in the question

Comment: It happens because you can not display image directly from local path, instead you have to read that image first from your local path(android device's path) , store result in variable and then assign that variable to <img src="variable here">.. i have done that also, i'm sharing my code with you. hop this will help you.